# MSVC 10 range based for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Currently in a large c++ project we are working on we have a bunch of the new style for loops like the following:

```
for (auto& value : values)
```

Up till now we have been compiling exclusively with gcc 4.6. Recently some of the codebase is being ported to windows and some of the developers want to compile in msvc++ 10 but it seems as though the new for loop syntax is not fully supported yet.

It would be highly desirable to not have to re-write all the places where this syntax occurs.

What is the best way to work around this problem?

Update: It looks as though this issue is resolved in MSVC11.

Comment: There's no way you're going to avoid some rewriting. VC++10 simply doesn't support it. And the only reason VC++11 will is because of the tireless efforts of the compiler writers, taking weekend time out to slip it into the build.

Comment: @NicolBolas: wow, I didn't know VC++ dev team was so devoted to their work. It's even more the pity that they are not further backed by Microsoft :x (as in: getting *more* devs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
//Using Xeo's example:
BOOST_FOREACH (auto& e, values) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Comment: Note that you can actually use `auto` here. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Of course... I was sitting in C++03 land for a bit there (;

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to replace them with `std::for_each` and lambdas, where possible. GCC 4.6 and MSVC10 both support lambda expressions.

```
// before:
for(auto& e : values){
  std::cout << e << " ";
}

// after:
std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(),
    [](a_type& e){
      std::cout << e << " ";
    });
```

The only caveat is that you need to actually type the element name (`a_type` here), and that you can't use control flow structures (`break`, `continue`, `return`).

Another way would be, when you need those control flow structures, to use old-style for-loops. Nothing wrong with them, especially with `auto` to infer the iterator type.

Yet another way might be to use the Visual Studio 11 beta when it's out, it supports range-based for loops IIRC. :)

Comment: Interesting idea, but the lack of control structures is definitely an annoyance.

Comment: "*Yet another way might be to use the Visual Studio 11 beta when it's out, it supports range-based for loops IIRC.*" Nope, not according to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, according to STL himself at [his GoingNative 2012 panel](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets). :) (Starting at somewhere around 38 minutes.)

Comment: Hmm, I haven't watched that yet. Are you sure he wasn't referring to VC++'s proprietary [`for each, in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx) construct? Because the current VC++11 docs don't reflect support for proper C++11 range-based `for` yet. **EDIT:** Just watched it (1:39 in), you're totally correct -- (good) news to me. :-D

Comment: @ildjarn: Just watch it, he was explicitly referring to range-based for-loop.

Comment: @Xeo: Why can't you write control flow structures?

Comment: @Nawaz : How would one `break` out of a lambda?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because the lambda is not a first-class part of the for-loop inside `std::for_each`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Oh I see what Xeo meant there. I just misunderstood it.

Comment: Do you know of any other new C++11 stuff (other than range-based for loops) not mentioned in the blog post?

Comment: @Jesse: range-based for is the only real language feature added to VC11 (which is a shame).

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks, I had my hopes up.. Although, according to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/02/03/10263262.aspx) new compiler and library features will be implemented more frequently after VC11 ships, so there is still some hope.

Comment: @Xeo: That's not entirely true. They'll have `enum class`, which is new in VC11. And their r-value reference support will be improved (though not to the point where they generate move constructors :( ). And their lambdas should be up to full C++11 compliance. Yes, it's not nearly as much as they *ought* to do, and they've got huge holes in their C++11 support. But it's something.

Comment: @Nicol: Right, thanks, I forgot scoped enums. However, I specifically said *added* language features. :)

Comment: @Xeo: On the other hand, I believe MSVC11 beta will be the first compiler to have a complete C++11 standard library implementation, no ? libstdc++ still lacks <regex> and <codecvt> and libc++ lacks <atomic>

Comment: @Thomas : Minus the C99 bits anyway.

Comment: @ildjarn The blog post has been updated to say that range-based for loops will be in VC11 Beta.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use boost.
Here's a simple macro for backwards compatibility with vs2010:

```
// 1600 is VS2010
#if _MSC_VER == 1600
    #define FOR_EACH(var , range) for each(var in range)
#else
    #define FOR_EACH(var , range) for (var : range)
#endif
```

Use it like this:

```
FOR_EACH(auto& e, values) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for each` itself

```
for each (auto value in values) {
std::cout << value << endl;
}
```