# Creating a brute-force algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, brute-force

I am trying to make a brute-force algorithm in C++, to solve problems. I have previously made a brute-force algorithm in Python but this used a 3rd party library, which means I can't convert it to C++. I quite like this design, that I have found;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string characters = "abcde";

    int length = 5;
    string word = "";
    for(int i = word.length(); i <= length; i++) {
        for(int l = 0; l < characters.length(); l++) {
            word += characters[l];
            cout << word << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

, but due to some bug(s), its output is:

```
abcdeabcde
abcdeabcdea
abcdeabcdeab
abcdeabcdeabc
abcdeabcdeabcd
abcdeabcdeabcde
```

and so on...
  The result, that I need is:

```
a
b
c
d
e
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bb
bc
...
```

Thanks In Advance :)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: that's not the output of your code

Comment: you want to make all possible permutations of that string and something more ...

Comment: Your not iterating through the string each time. I would use an array of chars for this.

Comment: A much better phrasing for this question is: "I want to generate all words in a language given an alphabet" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language (although as I worded it it is a bit confusing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach to generating all permutations is fundamentally flawed. Even if the bugs in your code were fixed, it would not behave the way you want.

Simply put, with a 2-level loop, you'll never hit the "aaa" permutation.

I would personally recommend a recursive approach, here's a rough starting point you can work around:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void visit(std::string const& chars, size_t max_len, std::string const& cur) {
    if(cur.length() == max_len) {
      return;
    }
    else {
      for(auto c : chars) {
        std::string next = cur + c;
        std::cout << next << std::endl;

        visit(chars, max_len, next);
      }
    }
}

int main() {
  visit("abcde", 5, "");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: me very much like this recursive approach :)

Comment: I am not the type of person whom copies someone's work and claims it as my own, I love programming and learning by myself but I was absolutely clueless. Thanks mate, this really helps! I dont use stack overflow much, how do I give you reputation points?

Comment: Just mark my answer as accepted (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Glad to be of help.

Comment: One thing I am concerned about is that on some compilers, this works fine and on other compilers it says "c does not name a type", along with "expected primary-expression before '}' token" and "expected ';' before '}' token" all on line 15. What's that about?

Comment: I wrote this code in C++11 out of reflex. That compiler probably is set to compile in C++03.

Comment: ***What's that about?*** Lack of c++11 support or not set to compile in c++11 mode.

Comment: Is Microsoft Visual Studio C++, C++11?

Comment: That depends on the version (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). The feature I'm using is called "Range-based for-loop". According to that matrix, it was introduced in MSVC 2012.

Comment: Is there any way to allow it to work on MSVC 2010?

Comment: Changing my code to use a traditional for loop is pretty trivial. I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: Use a regular for loop..

Comment: You can use a macro to make it backwards compatible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221842/msvc-10-range-based-for-loop

Comment: Thanks for all the help, you made my day!

Comment: Recursive functions are really not suitable in such a case. The process will end up using a lot of memory because of thousands of stack frames maintained by the routine calls. The process will eventually start trashing and maybe crash at some point.

Comment: @afr0ck What? no. The stack will only ever go as deep as max_len.

Comment: @Frank It doesn't matter, if you limit stack size then your software will have limits. For example, if you limit it to 2 MB with a stack frame of 4 Bytes (Very minimal) then the process can generate 250,000 words belote it halts. In case you set an unlimited stack size, process will consume a lot of physical memory and will start trashing & and at some point stack will overlap other segments (heap) in process virtual address space and will lead to failure and crash.

Comment: @afr0ck No, you are mistaken, you are assuming that the stack depth is proportional to the number of permutations, which is simply incorrect (it's logarithmic). There is a branching factor of `chars.length()` involved here. In my example, the recursion will only ever go 5 levels deep, even as it goes through 3125 permuations.

Comment: @afr0ck Or if you still don't believe me, just try it yourself, try `visit("abcdefghij", 100, "");` and see my code chew through 10^100 permutations like a champ (with a max stack depth of 100).

Comment: @Frank I've spent some time looking at your code and it seems fine. I think max stack frame depth is `max_len + 1` (+1 for the return check). However, i had positive intentions when i pointed out the stack overflow because i had doubt in using recursion for such a purpose. But this is some nice code you gave.